# TLS sequence number

Tags: numbers, sequence, ssl

I'm working on a college paper about TLS and I am asked why TLS sequence number counter is a 64-bit number when TLS only uses 32-bit sequence number in its messages. I've looked around for a while, even checked the RFC and I have found nothing so far. Can anyone help me?

Comment: From where do you get the *TLS only uses 32-bit sequence number in its messages*?

Comment: from my college papper... i'm supposed to answer why it only uses 32bit... i'm taking a master degree so i suppose the teacher didn't messed the question up...

Comment: I can find no source that says that it uses 32 bit sequence numbers anywhere. The RFC certainly defines it as 64-bit in section 6.1, and reaffirms this in section F.2.

Comment: @Yuliy I had the same problem. I've searched for a couple of hours so far and i've never seen any document stating it uses 32 bit! The only thing i've found is "(...) the sequence number must increase from 32 bits to 64 bits in order to be secure with static key usage (TLS gets away with the smaller sequence number because if it ever gets close to wrapping around, we can just trigger a new TLS handshake -- static keys need a large sequence number because they must be robust for long-term usage)" at http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2005-03/msg00280.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the question is just plain wrong. TLS uses 64-bit sequence numbers, and these are implicit (i.e. not transmitted as part of TLS messages).

Maybe the original questions is confusing SQNs in TLS with SQNs in IPsec: there, 32-bit sequence numbers are included in ESP and AH header fields, but 64-bit extended sequence numbers (ESNs) are permitted by the relevant RFCs.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the following quite from [RFC2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt), page 74, first paragraph, fifth sentence is an insufficient answer?

> Since sequence numbers are 64-bits
>   long, they should never overflow.

Comment: +1 with gratuitous pedantry - Section F.2 which is on page 72 as linked

Comment: I have already seen that, but my question is not whether the sequence number is 64bit or not... Why 64bit when in tls messages it only uses 32bit...

Answer (score 0):

There can be - and often are - differences between wording of the specification and any particular conforming implementation. English is an imprecise language for algorithm specification.

You fail to specify whether the implementation you are looking at **never** overflows in to bit 33, or if you've just not seen it happen. Claiming that you have seen the counter wrap modulo 2^32 would be a different claim altogether.

Comment: I don't have any implementation especification. It is a question. "Why is the TLS sequence number counter 64bit when only 32 bit are sent?"

Comment: It appears that English is not your first language. Please edit your question to add as much information as you can. The more words you use in describing your question the better we can guess what the problem is. Some of us will even clean up your wording for you, so don't be afraid to make mistakes.

Comment: Sorry about that! It's hard for me to translate technical english... The question is "Why is TLS sequence number counter 64bit long if only 32 bit are sent?" I'm going to put the original question in Portuguese here too "Porque razão o contador do número de sequência do TLS é a 64 bit se apenas são enviados 32 bit?"

Answer (score 0):

Please first understand what you are asking. What is a TLS message? Are you referring to TLS records? TLS uses a 64-bit counter for record messages and this number is not included in the TLS records. It is used implicitly.